# MySQL: Use Distinct Query, then join same table filtering with its result

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

After a few hours, and several dead-ends, I've decided to check with you guys. If there's a similar question/answer out there, and my lack of proper SQL understanding didn't help me get the gist of it, my apologies. But here goes:

My goal is to use one table to create a separated list of items for a checklist/to-do. Something like this:

```
 List title:
    |
    |---"First Entry Title" - "First Entry Body"
    |---"Second Entry Title" - "Second Entry Body"
    |--- Etc
```

I'm trying to do a Distinct search first, and use the results from that to filter the same table and join it with the alias 'items'. If there's a better way, then I wouldn't mind some assistance there. I just figured that would be the way about it.

I am currently using Sequelize, with the occasional raw query

I have a table of checklist entries, some rows share the same "parent", such as:

| parent | title | body |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | title1 | body1 |
| First | title2 | body2 |
| Second | title3 | body3 |
| Third | title4 | body4 |
| Third | title5 | body5 |

My goal is to have a query result like this:

| parent | title | body |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | title1 | body1 |
|  | title2 | body2 |

| parent | title | body |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Second | title3 | body3 |

| parent | title | body |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Third | title4 | body4 |
|  | title5 | body5 |

I realized a version of this was doable, when sequelize returned this to me in a different query:

```
{
"noteID":77,"noteContactID":"85","noteComment":"Test note","noteDate":1613429041844",
"Contact":{
     "contactID":85,"firstName":"Sully","middleName":null,"lastName":"Melland"
     }
}
```

However, this was done with two models, and likewise, two different tables.
I was hoping to avoid that approach, so I wouldn't need to make a full table just to filter by the "parent"

```
 Note.findAll({
        where: {noteContactID: req.params.id},
        include: [Contact]
    })
```

[List Example on project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16mcN.jpg)

[Table structure in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbG2X.jpg)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I doubt that you need two tables to make that work. You just need two (aliased) instances of the same table. Unfortunately, I don't know node.js/sequelize, but this is a doddle in pdo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a way where it will return one column name like 'first' and then give two rows of output in the next to columns. I think you can use a single column of type JSON to store {task-title:task-body}.

CREATE TABLE todo (Title varchar(255), Subtask JSON);

Then whenever you have any subtask, you can store it in JSON key-value pair. This you can store any number of subtasks, and you will need only 2 columns.

Comment: I can think of a way. Nevertheless, issues of data display are best resolved in application code

Comment: I think you will be better off by storing {key:values} pair JSON data in MySQL in the backend. I don't see any way to do what you want using distinct as if you apply distinct at the start, each entry will be different one and if you select just the title as distinct, you won't get those two rows and end up with just one.

Comment: I doubt that. But hey, maybe.

Comment: Shame, guess I'll have stick with two tables then, and make my life easier. Maybe in the future I'll be glad I did anyways!